# Cannot understand templates and constructor-related error

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum class demo_initialize { a = 1, b, c, d };

class Base {
public:
Base(demo_initialize initialize) : mInitialize(initialize) {}

protected:
demo_initialize mInitialize;
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base 
{
public:
Derived(T &value, demo_initialize initialize = demo_initialize::a) : Base(initialize), mValue(value), mLen(sizeof(T)) 
{
}

void display() { 
    cout << "Derived<T>{" << mValue << "; " << Base::mInitialize << "}";
}
protected:
T &mValue;
size_t mLen;
};

int main()
{
string string_to_reference = "world";
Derived<string> obj(string_to_reference, demo_initialize::c);
obj.display();

}
```

I was trying this piece of code.
while compiling I got error in this line:

```
cout << "Derived<T>{" << mValue << "; " << Base::mInitialize << "}";
```

and the error was

```
In instantiation of 'void Derived<T>::display() [with T =   std::basic_string<char>]':
37:17:   required from here
26:49: error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to   'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39:0,
             from 1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:602:5: note: initializing argument 1 of   'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT,   _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>;   _Tp = demo_initialize]'
 operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
```

I am not able to understand this error. Can somebody help me in solving this?

Comment: why you want to use `sizeof` on `string`?

Comment: `T &mValue;` should be `T mValue;` you are calling constructor of string and passing a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enum class values are treated as if they were a new type with no implicit cast to its underlying type. If you want to use `std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, const demo_initialize& )` on them, you need to provide one, or use:

```
void display() {
    auto mI = static_cast<std::underlying_type<demo_initialize>::type >(Base::mInitialize);
    std::cout << "Derived<T>{" << mValue << "; " << mI << "}";
  }
```

As for 'why' such a strange error about rvalues appear - blame standard library implementers ;).

Comment: enum class demo_initialize { a = 1, b, c, d };  i removed class from this statement and i  am getting the desired output. However can u explain how initializations are done in constructor of derived class.

Comment: Which initializations? Obj ones? you provide the reference to `string_to_reference` and `demo_initialize::c`. `Base` constructor is called with `intialize` as an argument which is a local `Derived` parameter `initialize` equal to `demo_initialize::c`. `string_to_reference` becomes `value`, which is assigned to `mValue` and `mLen` becomes `sizeof(std::string)` which is **not** the length of the string (use `value.length()` instead).

Comment: Thanx tsuki it was helpful. It would be a great favour if you clear one more doubt. I tried printing the value of 'mLen' inside display function and every time  I am getting its result as 8 regardless of string  i am entering. I am not able to understand what is this value 8 and what should be done to print the size of string I entered.

Comment: @NixiN See the last part of the last sentence of my last comment.

Answer (score 2):

`Base::mInitialize` is not automatically cast to an `int` in the line

```
cout << "Derived<T>{" << mValue << "; " << Base::mInitialize << "}";
```

Use:

```
cout << "Derived<T>{" << mValue << "; " << static_cast<int>(Base::mInitialize) << "}";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to call `operator<<` to stream a `demo_initialize`. Nowhere in your code have you defined this operator, and since `demo_initialize` is an enum that you defined yourself, there is no `operator<<` for it in the standard library either.

Solve this by implementing `operator<<(std::ostream &os, demo_initialize out)`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, demo_initialize out) {
    //Or some other logic, depending on the output format that you want.
    return os << static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<demo_initialize>>(out); 
}
```